# TypeError: len() of unsized object CNN error

Tags: python, deep-learning

I'm trying to run a CNN model for sentiment analysis and I get an error that shows:

> File "twitter-sentiment-cnn.py", line 292, in 
>       test_batches = list(batch_iter(zip(x_test, y_test), FLAGS.batch_size, 1))
>
> File
>   "/home/sanaa/Sentimental/Cnn/twitter-sentiment-cnn/data_helpers.py",
>   line 179, in batch_iter
>       data_size = len(data1) TypeError: len() of unsized object

```
 # Pretty-printing variables
if FLAGS.train:
# Batches
  batches = batch_iter(zip(x_train, y_train), FLAGS.batch_size, FLAGS.epochs)
  test_batches = list(batch_iter(zip(x_test, y_test), FLAGS.batch_size, 1))
  my_batch = batches.next()  # To use with human_readable_output()

global_step = 0
batches_in_epoch = len(y_train) / FLAGS.batch_size
batches_in_epoch = batches_in_epoch if batches_in_epoch != 0 else 1
total_num_step = FLAGS.epochs * batches_in_epoch

batches_progressbar = tqdm(batches, total=total_num_step,
                           desc='Starting training...')
```

And this is the function that causes the error:

```
def batch_iter(data, batch_size, num_epochs):
    """
    Generates a batch iterator for a dataset.
    """
    data = np.array(data)
    data_size = len(data)
    num_batches_per_epoch = int(len(data)/batch_size) + 1
    for epoch in range(num_epochs):
        # Shuffle the data at each epoch
        shuffle_indices = np.random.permutation(np.arange(data_size))
        shuffled_data = data[shuffle_indices]
        for batch_num in range(num_batches_per_epoch):
            start_index = batch_num * batch_size
            end_index = min((batch_num + 1) * batch_size, data_size)
            yield shuffled_data[start_index:end_index]
```

Comment: Verified xtest and ytest are not null at the point of error?

Comment: Is that the correct function? There's no `len(data1)` in it, it has `len(data)`.

Comment: it's a mistake it's "data"    , istill have the same error

Comment: Fine ... so what *is* `data` when you try to take its size?  I can't reproduce the error with your lack of supporting code or on my own.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: maybe try replacing `zip(x_test, y_test)` with `list(zip(x_test, y_test))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In python3, `len` cannot be used with iterators, and `zip` returns an a zip object, which is an iterator.  My guess is that np.array() preserves the iterator.  If you need the length, you may need to apply `list()`, though that may have scalability consequences.

Comment: yes you are right ! the problem with the version of python i must run the code with python 2.7

Comment: Note that I edited my answer to replace `unzip` with `list` (thanks @WillamPerron).  Applying `list()` would allow you to use python3.

Comment: If you find the answer acceptable, please select it (by clicking the checkmark) so that others can see in lists of new questions that yours has been answered acceptably to you.  It's also the best way to say "thanks."